# Fishpig Magento - Set a template for custom post type term view

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

Trying to set a template specifically for a particular term using the Fishpig Wordpres/Magento plugin.

I have a custom post type called 'Business' and have categories specific to this post type.

In /app/design/frontend/themes/default/layout/wordpress.xml I have the below that renders the template for all my category terms:

```
<wordpress_term_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="wordpress/term_view" name="wp.term" template="wordpress/term/view.phtml">
            <block type="wordpress/post_list" name="wordpress_post_list" as="post_list" template="wordpress/post/list.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</wordpress_term_view>
```

But what I need is a different template for a specific category 'executive interviews'.

You can see this here http://staging-ce.beanmediagroup.com.au/business/category/executive-interviews/.

**What I've tried**

I know you can set a unique page view using something like '' but this doesn't work with term ID.

I also know you can set a custom post list template for custom post types using something like `/wordpress/post/list/renderer/business.phtml` but this doesn't work for the terms.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check this file: **app/code/community/Fishpig/Wordpress/controllers/TermController.php** the **viewAction** you can see it's adding custom layout handles:

```
'wordpress_' . $term->getTaxonomyType() . '_view_' . $term->getId(),
'wordpress_' . $term->getTaxonomyType() . '_' . $term->getId()
```

which means, in your **app/design/frontend/themes/default/layout/wordpress.xml** if the ID of your desired category is 2 for example, you can add new handles specific for this category:

`<wordpress_category_view_2>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="wordpress/term_view" name="wp.term" template="wordpress/term/view.phtml">
            <block type="wordpress/post_list" name="wordpress_post_list" as="post_list" template="wordpress/post/list/renderer/business.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</wordpress_category_view_2>
//OR
<wordpress_category_2>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="wordpress/term_view" name="wp.term" template="wordpress/term/view.phtml">
            <block type="wordpress/post_list" name="wordpress_post_list" as="post_list" template="wordpress/post/list/renderer/business.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</wordpress_category_2>
//OR
<STORE_default_wordpress_category_view_2>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="wordpress/term_view" name="wp.term" template="wordpress/term/view.phtml">
            <block type="wordpress/post_list" name="wordpress_post_list" as="post_list" template="wordpress/post/list/renderer/business.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</STORE_default_wordpress_category_view_2>
//OR
<STORE_default_wordpress_category_2>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="wordpress/term_view" name="wp.term" template="wordpress/term/view.phtml">
            <block type="wordpress/post_list" name="wordpress_post_list" as="post_list" template="wordpress/post/list/renderer/business.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</STORE_default_wordpress_category_2>`

Just change the 2 with the ID of your category.

Answer (score 0):

zokibtmkd's post is pretty much correct and their method of finding the layout handles is a good one (working through the code until you find the answer), however you don't need to redfine all of the XML blocks and can just reference them instead. Also, you don't need to set post list renderer template via XML as the latest version of the extension will pick this up automatically.

First let's look at changing the post list wrapper template for terms (this defaults to wordpress/term/view.phtml).

```
<!--
/**
 * Change the wrapper template for 'category' with an ID of 2
 * Change '2' to the ID you wish to target
 * Change 'category' to the taxonomy name
 **/
-->
<wordpress_category_view_2>
  <reference name="wp.term">
    <action method="setTemplate">
      <template>wordpress/term/custom-template.phtml</template>
    </action>
  </reference>
</wordpress_category_view_2>
```

Now let's look how to change the post list render template.

It is possible to do this via XML as zokibtmkd stated however the latest version of Magento WordPress Integration does not require this. Instead, the extension will take the post type (in this case I believe the post type is 'business') and then look for a template of this name in the wordpress/post/list/renderer directory. **To change the post list template for this post type, create a file at wordpress/post/list/renderer/business.phtml**

Finally, if you wanted to **change the post view template for the 'business' post type, you would create a file at wordpress/post/view/business.phtml.**